# Implementing recommended formatting when using '%>%' and '+' together in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In Section 7.7 of 'R for Data Science', Hadley suggests using the following layout when combining the '%>%' and ggplot '+' operator:

```
diamonds %>% 
  count(cut, clarity) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(clarity, cut, fill = n)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

When you enter this in RStudio and use 'Code > Reindent Lines' however it changes to this:

```
diamonds %>% 
  count(cut, clarity) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(clarity, cut, fill = n)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

with an indent missing. Likewise when you type the '+' symbol and press enter, you are not given an automatic indentation. Is this simply a bug/bad design choice or is there a way in RStudio to enable the advised styling?

Comment: Code styling is a very opinionated topic and Hadley has his opinions and others have their own. You should focus on the style your future self will not look back on and wish they had a time machine to go back to and smack your current self. (Or the style the team you're on has defined as the preferred style). FWIW you can use the [`styler`](https://github.com/r-lib/styler) package to implement your own rules (and it comes with an RStudio plugin to reformat source file). Assuming anyone — even Hadley — is right about everything is likely a path fraught with ultimate peril.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Will take a look at styler. I wasn't using this style guide because it was Hadley's preference but because I think it's clearly the better way to format code. I only mentioned him since if this is his preference, it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume it might be somehow implemented in RStudio considering his position there.

Comment: FWIW I personally tend to caution (and grade as such when teaching) against piping into plots and also starting a pipe with a data object. I'm no "Hadley" but those choices have served me & my work quite well.  Also ref: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/rstudioconf2017

Comment: Try asking on community.rstudio.com for more of a discussion.